# Trying to push to personal github - but thinks I'm using work git

Tags: git, github, ssh

Recently got a work laptop with my work git and github accounts are connected via SSH however I started doing personal work on my work laptop and want to push to my personal github but I can't access it because it thinks I'm pushing from my work git. How do I fix this?

```
remote: Permission to Theqwertypusher/nextjs-blog.git denied to jvictor-wyze.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Theqwertypusher/nextjs-blog.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

My git repo is set up like this `origin  https://github.com/Theqwertypusher/nextjs-blog.git (fetch)`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, this has nothing to do with SSH, since the remote repository URL is an HTTPS one.

Check your credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If it returns, for instance, manager-core, type:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git-credential-manager-core erase
```

Then try to push again: a popup should ask you for your proper credentials (GitHub user account and password)

Replace "`manager-core`" by any other credential helper you might use.

If it does not find the `git-credential-xxx` executable, look for it in the Git installation path and use its full absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Von. The first command returned 'osxkeychain' but then it couldn't find the second command when I ran `printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git-credential-osxkeychain  erase `

Then I was denied permission when I used the absolute path of .git in my local repo `rintf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | /Users/jv/Documents/nextjs-blog/.git erase`

Comment: I meant the absolute path of the executable `git-credential-osxkeychain`, not of your repository.